# Defining a property of a JavaScript object in terms of another

Tags: javascript, object

I want to define one property of an object in terms of another, like this:

```
let obj = {
  prop1: some value,
  prop2: some expression in terms of prop1 (e.g. prop1 * 2)
}
```

So whenever I refer to prop2 in my code, that expression that I initialised it as will be evaluated. Is this possible?

Comment: This is a particularly clearly asked version of this question. I'm surprised not to have managed to find a good dupetarget for it. Giving up now. Anyway, even if someone finds one: Well-asked question!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder we got a standard canonical one…

Comment: @Bergi - I don't see that [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers) applies at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with an *accessor property* with a *getter* function:

```js
let obj = {
  prop1: 21,
  get prop2() {
    return this.prop1 * 2;
  }
};

console.log(obj.prop1); // 21
console.log(obj.prop2); // 42
```

If you like, you can also define a *setter* for it:

```js
let obj = {
  prop1: 21,
  get prop2() {
    return this.prop1 * 2;
  },
  set prop2(value) {
    this.prop1 = value / 2;
  }
};

console.log(obj.prop1); // 21
console.log(obj.prop2); // 42

obj.prop2 = 8;
console.log(obj.prop1); // 4
console.log(obj.prop2); // 8
```

More on MDN: [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set).

Finally, you can do it in class definitions, too:

```
class Example {
    constructor(prop1) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
    }
    get prop2() {
      return this.prop1 * 2;
    }
    set prop2(value) {
      this.prop1 = value / 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `prop2` be a `function` that fetches the value of `prop1`, performs some logic and returns the result. This way (if you want) you can even have the output of `prop2` to be up-to-date with the changes in `prop1`.

**Example:** (run it below)

```js
let obj = {
  prop1: 45,
  prop2 : function() {
    return this.prop1 * 3;
  }
};



console.log( obj.prop2() );
```